# Is it possible to calculate/estimate W2 based last paycheck?

Tags: united-states, taxes, paycheck, form-w-2

My wife and I just realized we are missing her W2. Her work will not be able to get it to us on time before tax day, so we'll most likely file an extension. Having said that, we still need to pay any taxes due - but don't want to pay more than we need. I'd like to estimate her W2 based on last paycheck, then input into turbotax and see what we owe. Can you point what paycheck values relate to W2 values, and how to calculate if it's not straight one-to-one?

Thanks!

Comment: How about last year's W2?  Is your wife's job so very different?

Comment: She wasn't working for a bit, and job/pay is totally different from previous years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few ways:

- If you have all of your pay stubs, you can calculate your gross pay.  If the deductions are broken out, you can calculate how much was withheld.
- If your pay stub has year-to-date totals for each deduction, take the last paycheck of the year to see what the 2012 totals were.
- If all of your paychecks are the same, you can estimate by taking the deductions and gross amount of one paycheck and multiply it by the number of paychecks to get the totals.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the Yer to date numbers on last paycheck of the year makes an excellent representative W2. All the numbers should be there.

Even though the numbers for 2011 were different from 2012 you should be able to compare the last paycheck stub from 2011 to the 2011 W2 as a guide.

You have to decide how close you want the estimate to be:

**Cautious approach:** To make sure you don't underpay, you can use the W2 to establish worst case numbers for your estimated taxes and extension: 
 - Wages: use the Gross pay from the stub. This ignores any nontaxable parts of your pay. 
 - Federal taxes
 - State taxes
 - Social security and medicare.

**Less cautious:** you might have to do some math.
 - Wages: look for a part of the pay stub that breaks out those items that aren't taxable. They might be in a separate section. They might have an * next to them. There might even be a line/box that says that the taxable pay was X. The non-taxable items include pretax-401K, health insurance, commuting costs. 
 - Federal taxes
 - State taxes
 - Social security and medicare.

It can be tricky if the company provided more free life insurance beyond $50,000, the amount they paid for the coverage is taxable.

You can't submit until you see the real W2 because you will be missing: the federal and state tax-id numbers for the company.

There can be a difference between the W2 and the pay stub, if there was a bonus check after the last paycheck. They had to make an adjustment to pay. My company had to adjust my pay because congress decided on Jan 2nd 2013 that more commuting costs were deductible retroactively back to January 2012.

Comment: The amounts withheld for Federal and State income taxes as well as for Social Security and  Medicare taxes **are** included in the **taxable** wages reported on the W2 form, whereas the nontaxable wages include the pretax 401k contributions, health insurance etc. You might be thinking about the _Net Pay_ line which is the sum total of the paychecks received or direct-deposited into the employee's bank account which is Gross Wages minus all the withholding amounts etc.

Comment: Some items reduce the taxable amount, some don't. For instance Long term disability might be included in taxable wages. My pay stubs report Gross, Taxable, and Net along with each individual item.

Comment: The point I was trying to make was that your statement "... non-taxable items include ... Federal taxes - State taxes - Social Security and Medicare." is flat out wrong. The items listed in the quote in the previous sentence **are** included in the Taxable wages, possibly not on your paystub but definitely on the W2. They are  not included in the Net Pay because the amounts are withheld and sent to the appropriate taxing authorities by the employer.